What precautions do I need to take when measuring 240VAC with a Hantek USB oscilloscope?
I am building a phase angle controller to control 240VAC power. I will need a way to measure the phase shift between input and output for which I am thinking of using my USB oscilloscope. This oscilloscope has two USB cables, one for data, which I will connect to an Android tablet. The other USB cable is for power which I am planning to connect to a USB power bank. This means the oscilloscope will be electrically floating with no connection to ground or live power.
I realize the conventional way would be to use differential probe,  this is a one off use case and I can't afford to shell out that kind of money.
All the tutorials and videos that I've reviewed for this seem to suggest that if the oscilloscope is "isolated" from mains power supply, it is safe enough to be used with mains power. In my case, the device is NOT connected anywhere whatsoever so I just wanted to get some opinions from wider community on what other precautions I should be taking in this case.
Please note that this is just a conversation, and I will not be holding anyone accountable for any damage. Also, if genuine risks are identified during this conversation, I will NOT proceed with the experiment and try to find some lab who can lend me their expensive equipment for a day. I would however prefer to do this at comfort of my home with equipment I've got.

Someone asked a very similar question recently: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/722859/active-differential-probe-or-isolated-differential-probe-to-measure-mains-safely

I normally measure between PE (earth) and the active. In your case the scope is not earthed, so that is the first task. Second is to determine if the probes (10:1) have an adequate voltage rating.

@Kartman And in case of dirt cheap Chinese oscilloscopes, step 3 would be to figure out how much of it you can trust and which parts that may randomly and spontaneously break or lose performance at any given moment. Just my experience from using such scopes over the years. I've had many probe failures, internal ground failures in the scope itself as well as spontaneous garbage displayed on the screen. To be compared with a super old analog Hameg scope I had which just worked all the time in every scenario... one knob got worn out from extensive use, that was the only failure it ever had.

How do you intend to operate the tablet touch screen?

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany Not really. I will preset the scope before powering on the mains.

First off:  Never float the scope.
This is just telling your circuit "go ahead and kill me now."
None of the Hantek USB scopes I've looked at is intended for operation this way.
They all have metal parts on the input side that will be connected to the live parts of your circuit.  Those metal parts are in no way isolated or even covered.
Take this example:

Pin 5 is a ground pin.  It is internally connected to the grounds of the BNC probe connections (marked 1 and 2.)  Whatever voltage you connect a probe to will appear on that pin.
As far as that goes, the grounds on the BNC connectors will all be tied together (unless the scope manual says otherwise.)  That means that whatever voltage you connect the first probe ground to will appear on the other BNV grounds.
You say that the second USB port supplies power to the input side of the scope.  That means that the USB port isn't isolated (if it were, you'd only need one instead of two.)  That puts the USB powerbank at whatever voltage is on the ground of the scope probes.
The whole mess is full of things waiting to bite you.  Connect the probe ground to a hot wire in your circuit, and a split second mistake can kill you dead.
Check here for more details on why it is bad to float an oscilloscope:
Why on earth are o-scopes earth referenced?

You can measure phase with a voltmeter. Measure input and output with respect to neutral. Then measure the difference between them. That gives you three sides of a triangle. The phase difference is the angle opposite the side that's the difference between input and output.

Whoever didn't like answer: care to say what you didn't like? Has the law of cosines been repealed?

With phase control there is no phase shift as such - a semiconductor device such as a Triac is used to ‘chop’ the waveform.
